# activemq embedded broker authentication

Tags: activemq-classic, jaas

I have embedded `activemq` broker.  I want to use `simpleAuthenticationPlugin`. I added dependency `activemq-jaas` for the embedded broker.
I have added setup for `simpleAuthenticationPlugin` but it seems trying to use my desktop username to authenticate or eclipse username (because it is the same username).

The following are the warnings:

> [WARNING] Failed to add Connection ID:JACTXML00124548-57386-1499699996538-1:1 due to java.lang.SecurityException: User name [MY DESKTOP USERNAME] or password is invalid.
>   [WARNING] Security Error occurred on connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:57387, User name [MY DESKTOP USERNAME] or password is invalid.

I cannot find anything suggesting that I need other configurations in the eclipse environment variables for the embedded broker.

Thanks a lot for any help or suggests.

Comment: You'll need to share the source code and/or any referenced configuration files to provide more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  It was due to spring's `context:property-placeholder` in my JmsClient's `application-context.xml`, I had `${USERNAME}`,`${PASSWORD}` which was trying to use environment variable instead of my `client.properties` file.

To avoid the issue, in both `application-context.xml` and `client.properties`, instead of having`${USERNAME}` and `${PASSWORD}`, I changed to `${CONSUMER_USERNAME}` and `${CONSUMER_PASSWORD}`.  It worked fine.